# I have a questions about bytes size of variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python newbie here.

I'm trying to write the function that divides input file into 'n' chunks, with no truncated lines. 
So size of each divided files not necessarily same. I'm just trying to divide it as same as I can.

the way I approached this problem is read the byte size of the input file (in this case, long string), divide that value by n , and then use that as a size limit of first n-1 files and the last file contains all remaining string

I think if i use this method, the last file may be inordinately large, as compared to the others.

But the issue is, the size of my last file is way bigger than my expectation.

For example, if I use this 545 byte size string:

```
input_string = '''
The Project Gutenberg EBook of Metamorphosis, by Franz Kafka
Translated by David Wyllie.

This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with
almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or
re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included
with this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.net

** This is a COPYRIGHTED Project Gutenberg eBook, Details Below **
**     Please follow the copyright guidelines in this file.     **


Title: Metamorphosis

Author: Franz Kafka

Translator: David Wyllie
'''
```

when n = 3, my code below generates 181, 199, and 261 byte size output, which is total of 641 bytes! how do I handle this issue?

```
n=3
i, j, k, z = 0, 0, 0, 0
rows = input_string.split('\n') #split string into 'nline' list elements
file_size = len(input_string.encode('utf-8')) #track bytes of input
size_limit = int(file_size / n)
size_each = 0


#create n number of empty list
lists = []
for z in range(n):
    lists.append([])

while i < (n-1):
    while size_each < size_limit:       
        lists[i].append(rows[k]+'\n')
        size_each = len(str(lists[i]).encode('utf-8'))
        k += 1
    print(size_each)
    size_each = 0
    i+=1

while k < len(rows):       
    lists[i].append(rows[k]+'\n')
    size_each = len(str(lists[i]).encode('utf-8'))
    k += 1
print(size_each)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to divide it into bytes, not characters? What is this for, if I may ask.

Comment: Have you tried printing out `str(lists[i]).encode('utf-8')` to see if it still looks like the input text?  My guess is that you've unintentionally inserted some extra bytes in there.

Comment: Hey Alexander! Yes, I'd like to divide this into byte. After I finish my division, I'll save those result as text file. So size of initial text file which is containing string need to identical with size of all divided n files.

Comment: Oh Sam, I tried what you said and it is printing string with unnecessary Parentheses, like b"['\\n']"
b"['\\n', 'The Project Gutenberg EBook of Metamorphosis, by Franz Kafka\\n']"

Comment: I think you are confusing bytes and characters.  Bytes are 8 bit.  Characters in Python3 can have between 1 and 4 bytes, as they are encoded in utf-8.

Comment: Oh now it make sense... I just simply thought each alphabet letters are 1 byte.

Comment: What is your variable `rows` mentioned in the code, but never given a value?

Comment: ahh i just have added it. it was 'input_string.split('\n')' . I counted number of new lines

Comment: cum_size is given an initial value, but never used?

Comment: yeah I declared it but never used it. I used size_each instead of it

Comment: Your problem is `str(lists[i])` which converts a list `['line1', 'line2']` into just the string `['line1', 'line2']`.  You'll want to use `''.join(lists[i[)`

Comment: oh, now it is working as what i expected! thank you JohanC!